# Notational difference between "+" and "∪" for defining a vector space from Lebesgue spaces.

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

I have a space $X$ defined in the literature as,

$X \in L^{\frac{3}{2}} + L^{\infty}$

is this denoting the union of the $L^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and $L^{\infty}$ spaces? If so, could it equally be written as,

$X \in L^{\frac{3}{2}} \cup L^{\infty}$

or is there a deeper difference between these expressions that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is *not* the same. The expression
>
> $$L^{\frac{2}{3}}+L^\infty=\{x+y|x\in L^{\frac{2}{3}},y\in L^\infty\}$$
>
> is the *sum* of vector spaces which is different from the union of both spaces.

See e.g. the Wiki-page about *[sum of subspaces](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Combining_Subspaces)* and this paper regarding *[sum of Lebesgue spaces](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Ejbhu/When%20is%20Lr%20contained....pdf)*.

Comment: Many thanks, this makes things much clearer.

I am just a physicist dipping my toes in analysis finding it hard to phrase things when googling them.

Comment: @JamesFurness: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful.